# Is there a conventional symbol for the set of radical expressions?

Tags: reference-request, notation, number-systems

There is already a question about the name of such a set:
[Name for numbers expressible as radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677057/name-for-numbers-expressible-as-radicals)

My question is related.

The rational complex numbers might be denoted ℚ(i), and the algebraic numbers are denoted . Between these two sets is that of radical expressions (the closure of the integers under arithmetic and radicals). Is there a conventional symbol for this set?

As an aside, are there any recommended references on the subject of radical expressions?

Comment: For your reference request, have a look at [this](http://education.wolfram.com/algebra/algebra-and-geometry-connections/radical-expressions/textbook.html).

Comment: Maybe you’re talking about the maximal solvable extension of $\mathbb Q$? There’s no standard notation.

Comment: Thanks @JoseArnaldoDris. Now I need to find a Windows machine to look at that site… (It says Linux is an unsupported platform!)

Answer (score 3):

There is no conventional symbol for the set of radical expressions.

If you find yourself needing one, just define one and be explicit about it.