# Name for numbers that are solutions to equations that are solvable by radicals

Tags: terminology, real-numbers, radicals

As is well-known, some algebraic real numbers can be expressed using radicals, and others cannot; for example, every real number that is a solution to a quadratic, cubic or quartic equation can be expressed using radicals, while solutions to higher-degree equations may not be.  Is there a standard convention for what to call this distinction?  I have heard the phrases "expressible numbers" and "inexpressible numbers" used orally, but never seen either one in print.

Context:  Many of my students are familiar with the distinction between rational and irrational numbers, but unaware that there are "types" of irrational numbers.  Ultimately I would like to be able to say

$$\mathbb Q \subset C \subset B \subset \mathbb A \subset \mathbb R$$

where $C$ denotes those real numbers that can be constructed using compass and straightedge, $\mathbb A$ denotes the algebraic real numbers, and $B$ describes the set of real numbers that can be expressed using radicals.  I am asking for a single-word description of the latter, in the same way that "constructible" is a concise description of the former.

Comment: There is the same question here, with no answer either https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677057/name-for-numbers-expressible-as-radicals?rq=1, I'm not sure there is even a name for $B$ other than "algebraic numbers expressible by radicals".

Comment: It is a reasonable question, but has been asked before.  See [Name for numbers expressible as radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677057/name-for-numbers-expressible-as-radicals).  If you want to have a one word term for them for pedagogical purpose, it will be incumbent on you to introduce that by definition, so perhaps have a bit of fun and call them EARs (expressible as radicals).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590563/algebraic-numbers-expressible-in-terms-of-real-valued-radicals) for the natural variant in which only *real-valued* radicals can be taken.